# Rust nalgebra - new_random() throws error for DMatrix

Tags: matrix, rust, nalgebra

Im trying to port https://github.com/markkraay/mnist-from-scratch to rust as an introduction to ML and the rust programming language.

I've decided to use nalgebra instead of rewriting a matrix library. However, im running into an error stating `` function or associated item not found in `Matrix<f64, Dynamic, Dynamic, VecStorage<f64, Dynamic, Dynamic>> `` when attempting to run new_random() on a DMatrix and I cant see how to fix It.

For context this is my code

```
pub fn new(input: usize, hidden: usize, output: usize, learning_rate: usize) -> NeuralNetwork {
        let hidden_weights = na::DMatrix::<f64>::new_random(hidden, input);
        let output_weights = na::DMatrix::<f64>::new_random(output, hidden);
        
        NeuralNetwork {
            input,
            hidden,
            output,
            learning_rate,
            hidden_weights,
            output_weights
        }
    }
```

Ive tried removing `<f64>` so that it is instead

```
na::DMatrix::new_random(hidden, input);
```

but there is no difference

Comment: The `new_random` function does not take any arguments. I think you want to call `new_random_generic`. Also make sure the `rand` feature is enabled on `nalgebra`.

Comment: @Locke [`new_random`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.31.4/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.new_random-3) can take arguments and OPs code compiles as posted with `rand` feature enabled. But admittedly it's a bit weird since it is implemented inside a macro.

Comment: @cafce how do you enable rand feature on nalgebra?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To use `new_random` you have to enable the `rand` feature of `nalgebra` like so in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
nalgebra = { version = "0.31.4", features = ["rand"] }
```

after that your code should work as you posted it.

If you have `cargo-edit` installed you can also do:

```bash
cargo add nalgebra --features rand
```